# How to change border bottom color of thead of datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I just wanted to change the border-bottom color of thead of datatable.
By default the border-bottom color of thead is black, need to change it to blue color

i have tried

which doesn't work
also put in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myThead").css("border-bottom-color", "red");
});
```

which also not work for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code works in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1fdqj5v8/. Please edit the question to include a working example of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The `border-bottom` property is not applied to the `thead` element but to `th` and `td` elements within the `thead` as you can see here :

```
table.dataTable thead th,table.dataTable thead td {
padding: 10px 18px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #111}
```

So you can change the color this way :

```
$(".myThead th").css("border-bottom-color","red")
```